# Filter data via ajax request in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, eloquent

This is my function in controller

```
public function ajaxResponse (Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $mat_id = $request->input('mat');
        $cat_id = $request->input('cat');
        $met_id = $request->input('met');
        if ($cat_id != null) {
            $products = Product::whereHas("categories", function ($query) use ($cat_id) {
                $query->whereIn('category_id', explode(',', $cat_id));
            })->get();
        }
        if ($mat_id != null) {
            $products = Product::whereHas("productMaterial", function ($query) use ($mat_id) {
                $query->whereIn('product_material_id', explode(',', $mat_id));
            })->get();
        }

        if ($met_id != null) {
            $products = Product::whereHas("productionMethod", function ($query) use ($met_id) {
                $query->whereIn('production_method_id', explode(',', $met_id));
            })->get();
        }
        if ($cat_id == null && $mat_id == null && $met_id == null) {
            $products = Product::all();
        }
        $prod = view('partials.ajaxProducts', ['products' => $products])->render();
    }
    return response()->json(['prod' => $prod]);
}
```

all the record filtered according to `$cat_id`, `$mat_id`,`$met_id`
here categories and **productMaterial** have Many to many relations with product and **productionMethod** have one to many relations with the product
i want to filter data via ajax request in combination with all these three relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function ajaxResponse(Request $request){
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $mat_id = $request->input('mat');
            $cat_id = $request->input('cat');
            $met_id = $request->input('met');

            $products = Product::query();
            if ($cat_id != null) {
                $products->whereHas("categories", function ($query) use ($cat_id) {
                    $query->whereIn('category_id', explode(',', $cat_id));
                })->get();
            }
            if ($mat_id != null) {
                 $products->whereHas("productMaterial", function ($query) use ($mat_id) {
                    $query->whereIn('product_material_id', explode(',', $mat_id));
                })->get();
            }
            if ($met_id != null) {
                $products->whereHas("productionMethod", function ($query) use ($met_id) {
                    $query->whereIn('production_method_id', explode(',', $met_id));
                })->get();
            }

            $products = $products->get();

            $prod = view('partials.ajaxProducts', ['products' => $products])->render();
        }
        return response()->json(['prod' => $prod]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
public function ajaxResponse(Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $mat_id = $request->input('mat');
        $cat_id = $request->input('cat');
        $met_id = $request->input('met');

        $products = Products::query(); 
        if ($cat_id != null) {
            $products = $products->whereHas("categories", function ($query) use ($cat_id) {
                $query->whereIn('category_id', explode(',', $cat_id));
            });
        }
        if ($mat_id != null) {
            $products = $products->whereHas("productMaterial", function ($query) use ($mat_id) {
                $query->whereIn('product_material_id', explode(',', $mat_id));
            });
        }
        if ($met_id != null) {
            $products = $products->whereHas("productionMethod", function ($query) use ($met_id) {
                $query->whereIn('production_method_id', explode(',', $met_id));
            });
        }

        $products = $products->get();

        $prod = view('partials.ajaxProducts', ['products' => $products])->render();
    }
    return response()->json(['prod' => $prod]);
}
```

Comment: message: "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 
1: {function: "ajaxResponse", class: "App\Http\Controllers\FrontEndController", type: "->"}
class: "App\Http\Controllers\FrontEndController"
function: "ajaxResponse"
type: "->"
i got this error in xhr response

Comment: @ChandraGhimire Sorry for that, I've updated code. Take a look now.